# Error 500 from youtube.channels.list API

Tags: youtube-api, google-api, youtube-data-api

I'm passing the following to the `youtube.channels.list` method in the YouTube Data API (v3).

```
[key] => foo,
[forUsername] => royaloperahouse,
[part] => topicDetails
```

But my response just contains a `500 Internal Server Error`:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 500,
        "message": null
    }
}
```

I get the same behaviour from the Google Developers Console. What could be causing this? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YouTube confirmed this was an API bug and it was subsequently fixed.